# Socket.io emit events not updating the client side until the io.on('connection) functions reaches the end

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am making a blockchain in Node.js and updating the client side with socket.io. I want to add a new block to a list on the client side everytime a new block is generated, but they all get added together at the end when generating is finished. I have an emit event fire everytime after a new block is generated ( inside of a for loop ), so I don't know why the client side only updates when all of the blocks are generated.So basically they all get added at the same time instead of one by one. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**client.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);
const myArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
const port = myArgs[0];
const SHA256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");
var indexNumber = 1;
var difficulity = 4;
var Nonce = 0;
const data = "This is block ";


class Block {
    constructor(index, timestamp, data, previousHash, diff, nonce) {
        this.index = index;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.data = data;
        this.previousHash = previousHash;
        this.diff = diff;
        this.nonce = nonce;
        this.hash = this.generateHash();
    }
    generateHash() {
        var good;
        var failed = 0;
        while (true) {
            good = false;
            var newHash = SHA256(this.index + this.timestamp + this.previousHash + JSON.stringify(this.data) + this.diff + this.nonce).toString();
            for (var i = 0; i < this.diff; i++) {
                if (newHash[i] == '0')
                    good = true;
                else {
                    good = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (good) {
                io.emit('goodHash', (newHash + " Difficulity: " + this.diff));
                break;
            }
            else {
                this.nonce++;
                if (failed == 30000) {
                    io.emit('wrongHash', (newHash + " Difficulity: " + this.diff));
                    failed = 0;
                }
                else
                    failed++
            }
        }
        return newHash;
    }

}

class Blockchain {
    constructor() {
        this.blockchain = [this.createGenesisBlock()];
    }

    createGenesisBlock() {
        var tmp = new Block(0, Date.now(), "Genesis block", "0", difficulity, Nonce);
        io.emit('newBlock', JSON.stringify(tmp));
        console.log(tmp);
        return tmp;
    }

    getTheLatestBlock() {
        return this.blockchain[this.blockchain.length - 1];
    }

    addNewBlock(newBlock) {
        this.blockchain.push(newBlock);
    }

    validateBlock(newBlock) {
        const latestBlock = this.getTheLatestBlock();
        if (newBlock.previousHash !== latestBlock.hash)
            return false;
        if (newBlock.index <= latestBlock.index)
            return false;
        if (newBlock.hash !== SHA256(newBlock.index + newBlock.timestamp + newBlock.previousHash + JSON.stringify(newBlock.data) + newBlock.diff + newBlock.nonce).toString())
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    validateChain() {
        for (let i = 1; i < this.blockchain.length; i++) {
            const currentBlock = this.blockchain[i];
            const previousBlock = this.blockchain[i - 1];
            if (currentBlock.hash !== SHA256(currentBlock.index + currentBlock.timestamp + currentBlock.previousHash + JSON.stringify(currentBlock.data) + currentBlock.diff + currentBlock.nonce).toString()) {
                return false;
            }
            if (currentBlock.previousHash !== previousBlock.hash) {
                return false;
            }
            if (currentBlock.index <= previousBlock.index)
                return false;
            return true;

        }
    }
}
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('set transports',() =>{
        socket.transports = ["websocket"];
    });
    console.log('GUI connected on port: ' + port);
    io.emit('onConnection', port);
    socket.on('mine', function () {
        console.log("mining in progress...");
        let logCoin = new Blockchain();
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            while (true) {
                var tmp = new Block(indexNumber, Date.now(), data + indexNumber, logCoin.getTheLatestBlock().hash, difficulity, Nonce);
                if (logCoin.validateBlock(tmp)) {
                    io.emit('newBlock', JSON.stringify(tmp));
                    console.log(tmp);
                    logCoin.addNewBlock(tmp);
                    indexNumber++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //console.log(logCoin);
        //io.emit('blockLedger', JSON.stringify(logCoin, null));
    })



    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log("Client has disconnected");
        indexNumber = 1;
    });
});

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening on port ' + port + ':');
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
    body {
        margin: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 3rem;
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    #header {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    #contentWrap {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 10px;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #contentWrap>div {
        flex: 1;
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: visible;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    #blocks {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #blocks>li {
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }

    #minedBlocks {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #minedBlocks>li {
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }

    #port {
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="element1">
            <h1>Blockchain</h1>
            <p id="connectionStatus">Status: Offline</p>
            <form id="form" action="">
                <button id="mine">Mine</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="element2" style="align-self: center;">
            <form id="form" action="">
                <div id="port">
                    <input id="portInput" autocomplete="off" /><button>Connect port</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentWrap">
        <div id="ledger">
            <ul id="blocks">
                <li>Blockchain ledger</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="mined">
            <ul id="minedBlocks">
                <li>Mining...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
        var mine = document.getElementById('mine');
        function padTo2Digits(num) {
            return num.toString().padStart(2, '0');
        };

        function formatDate(date) {
            return (
                [
                    padTo2Digits(date.getDate()),
                    padTo2Digits(date.getMonth() + 1),
                    date.getFullYear(),
                ].join('.') +
                ' ' +
                [
                    padTo2Digits(date.getHours()),
                    padTo2Digits(date.getMinutes()),
                    padTo2Digits(date.getSeconds()),
                ].join(':')
            );
        };

        function printBlock(block, parent, div) {
            var formattedDate;
            var timeStamp;
            let item = document.createElement("li");
            item.style.color = "green";
            item.textContent = "Index: " + block.index + "\r\n";
            item.textContent += "Data: " + block.data + "\r\n";
            timeStamp = new Date(block.timestamp);
            formattedDate = formatDate(timeStamp);
            item.textContent += "Timestamp: " + formattedDate + "\r\n";
            item.textContent += "PreviousHash: " + block.previousHash + "\r\n";
            item.textContent += "Difficulity: " + block.diff + "\r\n";
            item.textContent += "Nonce: " + block.nonce + "\r\n";
            item.textContent += "Hash: " + block.hash + "\r\n";
            parent.appendChild(item);
            div.scrollTop = ledger.scrollHeight;
        }

        socket.on('onConnection', function (msg) {
            document.getElementById('connectionStatus').innerText = "Status: Online: PORT " + msg;
        });
        socket.on('blockLedger', function (msg) {
            var blocks = document.getElementById('blocks');
            var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
            var ledger = document.getElementById('ledger');
            obj.blockchain.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
                printBlock(arrayItem, blocks, ledger);
            });
        });
        socket.on('wrongHash', function (msg) {
            var minedBlocks = document.getElementById('minedBlocks');
            var mined = document.getElementById('mined');
            let item = document.createElement("li");
            item.style.color = 'red';
            item.textContent = msg;
            minedBlocks.appendChild(item);
            mined.scrollTop = mined.scrollHeight;
        });
        socket.on('goodHash', function (msg) {
            var minedBlocks = document.getElementById('minedBlocks');
            var mined = document.getElementById('mined');
            let item = document.createElement("li");
            item.style.color = 'green';
            item.textContent = msg;
            minedBlocks.appendChild(item);
            mined.scrollTop = mined.scrollHeight;
        });

        socket.on('newBlock', function (msg) {
            var blocks = document.getElementById('blocks');
            var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
            var ledger = document.getElementById('ledger');
            printBlock(obj, blocks, ledger);
        });

        mine.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('mine');
        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Edit**
I am still trying to find a solution. I tried changing the socket io transport options in both the .js file and index.html, flushing the buffer and using volatile.emit but nothing worked. I think for some reason the emits get buffered and then sent at the end, but i dont know why.

Also, the first two emits execute well (so the 'onConnection' is first and either the 'wrongHash' or 'goodHash' second), but everything after that is sent (or received) after the for loop is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should call your emit function on

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        while (true) {
            var tmp = new Block(indexNumber, Date.now(), data + indexNumber, logCoin.getTheLatestBlock().hash, difficulity, Nonce);
            if (logCoin.validateBlock(tmp)) {
                //here you should write this
                io.emit('newBlock', JSON.stringify(tmp)); //this is where the new block is emmited
                logCoin.addNewBlock(tmp);
                indexNumber++;
                break;
            }
        }
        //not here 
        io.emit('newBlock', JSON.stringify(tmp)); //this is where the new block is emmited
        console.log(tmp);
    }
```

Comment: it still doesnt work

Comment: @JakobKrajnc this should work. are you getting same behaviour with this implementation?

Comment: @Yilmaz yes, it's still the same